# QGIS Reclassify with raster calculator to NaN

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I would like to use raster calculator in QGIS to convert all values `<= -500` to `NA` values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is a trick for using if/else in calculator. It can be used for your question. Type following code into raster calculation expression:

```
("gurbeyli@1"<=-500)*-9999 + ("gurbeyli@1">-500)*"gurbeyli@1"
```

And of course "gurbeyli@1" is my raster band name, you should use yours.
In this example, -9999 was used as NA value:
[image]